# how can i edit this AHK script to make it toggle?

Tags: autohotkey, code

So I have this script (thanks is due to whoever):

```
lctrl::
 {
   toggle:=!toggle
 }

[color=red]~[/color]lbutton::
 {
   if toggle
```

When holding <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, it prevents the scripts from working.  How do I make it so that only one press of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> is required to prevent the other scripts from working?  Then when pressed again the scripts start working again.

Answer (score 1):

This will let you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> once to toggle, and left-click will rapid-repeat whatever command you insert in Line 6.

```
lCtrl::toggle:=!toggle

~lButton::
    if toggle  ; Only run if toggle is on
        while, getKeyState("lButton")  ; Repeat if left-click is held
            ; Insert left-click function here
return
```

You can prevent other hotkeys from working by including the `if toggle` condition in their definitions:

```
$a::
    if toggle  ; Only run if toggle is on
        msgBox Toggle is on, you pressed A.
    else  ; Do nothing if toggle is off
        send a
return
```